# Have a filtered value and total grouped by date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently working on PostgreSQL having 2 data tables, Operator and Order.

Each Operator does an order and this will create a new order with its name, date and Operator ID.

I want to display, for each day where there have been at least one order, the total number of orders done by all the operators and the number of order of a specific operator that I put the id.

I'm actually doing:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(Order.order_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as orderDate,
COUNT(Order.order_index) AS totalOrders
FROM Order
LEFT JOIN Operator ON Order.op_id = Operator.operator_id
AND TO_DATE(order_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN '01/10/2021' AND '22/10/2021'
group by orderDate
ORDER BY orderDate ASC
```

This displays for each day the total number of orders done by all the operators :

```
2021-10-15 | 3
2021-10-16 | 2
2021-10-18 | 4
```

I would like to be able to put on a third column the number of orders done by the operator with operator_id = 6

```
2021-10-15 | 3 | 0
2021-10-16 | 2 | 2
2021-10-18 | 4 | 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`FILTER` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES):

```sql
count(*) filter (where Order.op_id = 6)
```

This will only count the rows where the expression yields true.

Alternatively, you can use a `CASE`:

```sql
count(case when op_id = 6 then 1 end)
```

This relies on the fact that `COUNT` only counts non-NULL values, and the default for [`CASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) is `NULL` when no `WHEN` clause matched.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(Order.order_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as orderDate,
COUNT(Order.order_index) AS totalOrders,
SUM(CASE WHEN Order.op_id = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS totalOrdersOperator6
FROM Order
WHERE TO_DATE(Order.order_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') BETWEEN '01/10/2021' AND '22/10/2021'
group by orderDate
ORDER BY orderDate ASC
```